# Get values of userAccount upon Login

Tags: php, authentication, session-state, session-variables

I am creating a login system for my website. I want to grab the user's userID (aka a primary key out of the database) to use when they log in.

I have 3 files I'm using:

**/index.php - that is basically the login form with a username and password fields. It contains this php code:**

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
?>
```

**Once form is submitted, it goes to check_buyer.php**  (/check_buyer.php)

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged 

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt, uUserType FROM User WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        #header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return true;
}

function validateUser() {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = (isset($ifUserExists['uID'])) ? $ifUserExists['uID'] : null;
    echo 'sessuID: '.$_SESSION['uID'];
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
// If User *has not* logged in yet, keep on /login
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

**If the credentials are valid, the user is sent to login_new/buyer/index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['uUserType'] != 1) // error
{ 

    die("
    <div class='container_infinity'>
        <div class='container_full' style='position:static;'>
        <img src='img/error/noAccess.png' style='float:left;' /> <br />
        <h2>403 Error: You may not view this page. Access denied.</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    ");
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    return ($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1);
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1 && $_SESSION['uUserType'] == 1){
        #echo "<a href='../logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        echo 'buyerid: '.$_SESSION['uID'];
        require_once('buyer_profile.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

The problem is, when I login with valid credentials it sends me to login_new/buyer/index.php with the account, but is not outputting the buyer ID using the code `echo 'buyerid: '.$_SESSION['uID'];`  what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try commenting the `header()` redirect and echo the `$_SESSION['uID']` right after you set it in function `validateUser()` to see if the session data is actually set right there

Comment: Please see revised check_buyer.php above, this hasn't done anything . the variable is still blank

Comment: you should now have the page not redirecting but just outputting a blank page. What I ment was this. To see if the variable is set correctly in the check_buyer.php page itself. 

`function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
echo $_SESSION['uID']   
#header( 'Location: buyer/' );
echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
return true;
}`


Sorry for the bad aligning, it won't let me align properly